# Javascript - splitting string with use of regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

Maybe there is solution righ in front of my nose but i cant see it.

```
var expr = "-5+6.3x24";
console.log(expr.split(/([+\-x\/])/));
```

Output is logically:

```
["", "-", "5", "+", "6.3", "x", "24"]
```

But what i need is following:

```
["-5", "+", "6.3", "x", "24"]
```

I need to split this string by separators +,-,x,/, but not when is the separator at the beginning of string. 
Any ideas how to edit this code?
Thanks alot.

Comment: `expr.match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\S/g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var expr = "-5+6.3x24";
console.log(expr.split(/(?!^)([+\-x\/])/));
```

Comment: This solution will produce the appropriate result for that specific example. However, it will probably give an undesired result for other examples like `"5x-5"` that gives `["-5", "x", "", "-", "5"]`.

Comment: True, but there is no reason to have such syntax, this is not a valid mathematical syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working marvelously. Example like "5x-5" is in my case evaluated like err.